# Выведение infowindow google maps api 3. Не получается вывести

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

С горем по полам собрал карту. Но не могу понять как выводить свой infowindow при клике на каждый маркер. Подскажите, пожалуйста!

```js
   function initMap() {

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 6,
          center: {lat: 49.697722, lng: 33.225358},
          navigationControl: true,
   styles: [
    {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#444444"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#f2f2f2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "saturation": -100
            },
            {
                "lightness": 45
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "simplified"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "labels.icon",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "visibility": "off"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "all",
        "stylers": [
            {
                "color": "#46bcec"
            },
            {
                "visibility": "on"
            }
        ]
    }
]  
});

   

        // Add some markers to the map.
        // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
        // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
        // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
        var markers = locations.map(function(location, i) {
          return new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            icon: image
          });
          marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
        });


        // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
        var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
            {imagePath: 'http://spektrum.ua/images/placeholder'});
      }
    var image = 'http://spektrum.ua/images/placeholder.png';
      var locations = [
                {lat: 49.981919, lng: 36.232537},
                {lat: 49.964425, lng: 36.221476},
                {lat: 50.456978, lng: 30.437191},
                {lat: 48.448276, lng: 35.032237},
                
             
        {lat: 0, lng: 0}
      ]
```

```css
 #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
 <script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC-4Y95P4YUPBuNj3LuiU-_YIuna4RhAiM&callback=initMap">
    </script>
<div id="map" style='height:400px;width:100%;'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var coordInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var windowPos = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
coordInfoWindow.setContent(createInfoWindowContent(windowPos, map.getZoom()));
coordInfoWindow.setPosition(windowPos);
coordInfoWindow.open(map);
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple